# python-igraph find shortest path only if attributes corresponds to a condition

Tags: python, igraph

My graph is constructed from a db query where the result has following columns:

```
source, target, weight, param
```

The graph s constructed like this:

```
graph = igraph.Graph.DictList(vertices=None, edges=result, edge_foreign_keys=('source', 'target'))
```

I can find the shortest path without problem by using

```
dist = graph.shortest_paths_dijkstra(source='5501362',  target='5514175', weights='weight')
```

also I can list all nodes composing my path by

```
path = graph.get_shortest_paths('5501362',  to='5514175', weights='weight')
```

But I have to add a condition where I only select edges which correspond to param=10

How to add this condition to my shortest paths queries?

**Edit**:
Here is the code I'm using:

```
most = time.time()
with pyodbc.connect(connstr) as db:
    cr = db.cursor()
    rows = cr.execute(_sql).fetchall()
    db_cols = [column[0] for column in cr.description]

    result = []
    for row in rows:
        result.append(dict(zip(db_cols, row)))

print(f"DB query time: {time.time()-most}")
most = time.time()
graph = igraph.Graph.DictList(vertices=None, edges=result, edge_foreign_keys=('source', 'target'))
print(f"graph construction time: {time.time()-most}")
most = time.time()
dist = graph.shortest_paths_dijkstra(source='5501362',  target='5514175', weights='weight')
print(dist)
print(f"shortest_paths_dijkstra time: {time.time()-most}")
most = time.time()
path = graph.get_shortest_paths('5501362',  to='5514175', weights='weight')
print(f"get_shortest_paths time: {time.time()-most}")
```

Comment: Just construct a new graph (or a subgraph, which amounts to the same thing) using only edges that fulfill your condition; perform the shortest path search on that.

Comment: Well, even tough it might me a solution but certainly not the most optimistic.  The graph is quite big and in my environment I have several kind of conditions. It would be crazy to build one complete and several subset of that graph, where every information is already stored at node level

Comment: Recall that the time complexity of Dijkstra is O(E + V log (V)); subgraph construction is O(E + V) (depending on the data format, really, but it will be something like this), so the latter won't be your rate limiting step in this computation.

Comment: Paul, this is not the point. I'm constructing the graph once and query it many times (about 100-200 times per minute). So I will not construct the graph each time The parameters are just like in any route planner, like Waze, (is the track electrified, is there any speed or weight limit, is at the node level a bidirectional exit, etc.) So there is real need for a conditional search. At least for us.

Comment: My point is that each graph construction will probably be quite a bit shorter than each query, so in the grand scheme of things having a graph construction up front will not slow down your execution time substantially. In fact, if you look closely, it will probably speed up the shortest path computation, as potentially the subgraph will have many fewer edges and nodes. A conditional search that you are imagining would have to check against the complete set of nodes and edges. So it might seem like you are doing extra work, but really you are reducing the problem up front.

Comment: But the algorithm is looking for all nodes anyhow because it is a weighted graph. So it has to pick the weight attribute to use for calculation (weights='weight'). So if it is taking the weight attribute, it could take IMHO any other attribute/condition as well without any extra cost.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) Not all weighted graphs are complete, and the implementation in `igraph` will be written in a way that reflects that. 2) Checking for a second condition always incurs a cost. 3) At this stage, I don't know how to convince you other than urging you to familiarize yourself again with the basic Dijkstra algorithm, and maybe even read the source code. 4) Prove me wrong by making your own implementation and timing it. My claim: the time complexity of subgraph construction and subgraph query is no longer than a conditional query on the full graph.

Comment: As you can see the graph consrtuction's time (with DB access) is around 100 times slower than the search itself.: graph construction time: 0.26601505279541016
shortest_paths_dijkstra time: 0.0030002593994140625
get_shortest_paths time: 0.002000093460083008

Comment: The graph construction time with DB access is potentially meaningless if the DB access dominates the construction time. Starting with an edge list in memory, how long is the construction time actually? This is also the more relevant case when you induce a subgraph by selecting edges matching your desired parameter.

Comment: As you can see, the graph construction time based on an already in memory dict structure is still 5 times more than the query time.  DB query time: 0.24001383781433105
graph construction time: 0.01000070571899414
shortest_paths_dijkstra time: 0.002000093460083008
get_shortest_paths time: 0.0009999275207519531